# Cron job running (?) and output file is being logged every night at 1:35am, but there is nothing listed in crontab -l

Tags: macos, script, launchd, cron

I recall creating a cron job that runs a shell script that deletes files that are 45+ days old. When I was editing `crontab -e` I set it to also output a log to a date stamped log file to `~/Logs`.

I want to remove this job, and now I cannot find it. Nothing shows up under `crontab -l` and I also checked `launchctl list` (as I wasn't sure if I made it a launchd job) but couldn't find anything there.

I know that the script name is `remove_old_clips.sh` so I tried various ways to `find` and `fgrep` for the string '`remove_old_clips`' inside every file on the computer to see if I could locate where the job was being performed.

Nothing is located in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs/` either.

If I know the name of the script, and I know where it is being logged to, how can I find what is automatically running this task every night at 1:35am?

Comment: In addition to the per-user crontab files, there can also be a system crontab, probably at /etc/crontab. There might also be /etc/cron.* directories. Check to see if it's in any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have been a bug. As soon as I opened `crontab -e` when I was initially trying to work on this, it stopped logging. Not sure how or why my initial `crontab` jobs were erased, but I simply recreated them and everything is fine now.